# CyrstalReport connection to Oracle DB on ASP.NET site do not work

Tags: asp.net, oracle, crystal-reports, odbc

I setup a small asp.net site with CrytsalReportViewer web component (V13). The display of reports works well and now I would like to refresh the data in the report.

The report was created with Oracle ODBC connection and works on my PC. When I try to refresh data on the asp.net web site, which runs on WinXP (32Bit), CR shows me always a dialog to enter/verify db values like server name, user and password.

The DB values are correct and the Oracle ODBC Client (10.2.0.1) 32Bit is installed and configured. I can tnsping my database and the ODBC connections works well too. It looks like CrystalReports cannot find the ODBC which is specified in the report although the ODBC connection with this name exists.

Any idea what I can check to make it work?

Is there any logfile of CrystalReportViewer component to see why CR cannot connect?

Thanks in advance,
AlexS

Comment: You may declare a separate connection string for your CrystalReportViewer.

Comment: What do you mean with separate connection string? In my ASP page I set already all necessary db values and it works well on my development pc.

Answer (score 0):

I Got it. After installing another Oracle client (11g R2) it works perfectly. It seems that old Oracle client 10.2.0.1 is not full comapatible with the current CrystalReportViewer version.